Prevent flyway from logging failed SQL statements
I am currently evaluating the usage of Flyway to execute SQL migrations with placeholders that may be values that we do not want to be leaked in logging output. Curently if the query fails this is the output that flyway provides (sample example with creating role):
-----------------------------
SQL State  : 42601
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: unrecognized role option "login22"
  Position: 30
Location   : ...
Line       : 1
Statement  : CREATE ROLE test_marcin with LOGIN22 PASSWORD 'secret-password-value'

I tried to search extensively on the web but failed to find any configuration option or solution that would prevent FLYWAY from logging SQL queries that failed to execute or prevent logging evaluated values of the placeholders.
Does anybody faced a similar issue and found a solution?

Not a fix per say and I am assuming you are using Postgresql from the SQL State code so apologies if this is not relevant. However, Is there any requirement for this password to be stored in plain text? With Postgresql you can pre-encrypt passwords (the default it MD5 hashs the password). That would help secure you against any one being able to see your password from either the exception handling or hacking into your placeholders.

Good news, latest versions of Flyway Engine (10.13.0+) will only output the SQL if the -X debug flag is supplied
